# Can we both upgrade to SharePoint 2013 from 2010 and move domain at the same time?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, upgrade, domain

We have 2 tasks to do and I am looking for some advice.

We need to upgrade from 2010 to 2013 and we need to move the farm to a new domain.  I was thinking of doing the upgrade first and then the domain change but I was wondering if it would be better to build a new farm on the new domain and do a database attach upgrade.

- How would this effect the links in the sites?
- What is the best practice on this?
- If you have done this, what were your problems?

Comment: In our current setup, the 2 domains have full trust and most (if not all) of our users have user accounts on both domains so the users are not worrying me.  What is worrying me are the links and whether to do the new farm on the new domain and then db attach the old 2010 content dbs to the new farm and upgrade them or do the farm on the old domain upgrade and move to the new domain.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to go ahead and architect out the new 2013 farm, get it built, and proceed with the database attach upgrade.

1. It will not impact the links of the site unless your URL changes.  Your URL shouldn't have to change unless you are using the server name as the URL. (a lot of the links will automatically upgrade themselves anyway, but manually entered links are unlikely to change by themselves.)

   2. Best Practice for a 2010 to 2013 migration would generally be 'Build a new farm and do a database attach upgrade'  The domain migration is a separate beast.
   3. I'm assisting with several sites doing domain migrations and their biggest issues have to do with where their customers are.  If you are using anything other than Forms authentication, moving your servers is nice and all, but will the customers still be able to authenticate on the new domain?  Building the farm out in the new domain helpfully bypasses service account issues.  So that one is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you have to run move-spuser after changing the domain to migrate the user from old domains to new domain. I am sure changing the Domain of SharePoint is not supported.

In your situation, I would do the following way.

- Setup new SharePoint 2013 farm in new domain, Configuring the Web Applications and Service Applications.
- Test your SharePoint 2013 configuration.
- Now restore the 2010 database into 2013 farm and upgrade them
- Now run the Move-spuser to migrate all users from old domain to new domain.
- Test it.

here are some good reference: http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2011/09/23/move-sharepoint-2010-server-to-another-domain/ this is for 2010 but give you all the information.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx